# Google Maps API and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3, maps, geocoding

I am new to Google Maps API and I have a requirement to integrate Google Maps API with an ASP.Net application. Is there a Google service where in I can input a UK postcode and radius as input parameters  and get results only, without the map.

For example if I search for solicitors in a particular area like Z1 1XY (not real post code) with a radius of 5 mi, can I get the results of all solicitors with the postcodes 5 mile radius? Is there any service that would return the result set only? I know GeoCoding does something similar but can I provide radius as one of the input parameter and get results.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Seaton

Comment: Have you looked at Google Places API? https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12).

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Comment: sure I will forward that to the concerned person on the usage restrictions.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best you can do. Then... it's up to them. You can accept this answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can use the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to do address lookups (in this case postcodes). The response contains lat/lon co-ordinates which you can then subsequently use as the epicenter of your search to find items within a radius. Have a look at this [blog post](http://cmatskas.com/working-with-dbgeography-points-and-polygons-in-net/) on how to use the DbGeography in .NET to perform radius queries based on lat/lon co-ordinates.

Comment: Sorry, but while your answer might be correct, it is against Google's Terms of Service as OP mentioned that he wanted to use it *without the map*. See my answer.